# URL with no query parameters - How to distinguish

Tags: c#, .net, .net-1.1

Env: .NET 1.1

I got into this situation. Where I need to give a URL that someone could redirect them to our page. When they redirect they also need to tell us, what message I need to display on the page. Initially I thought of something like this.

- http://example.com/a.aspx?reason=100
- http://example.com/a.aspx?reason=101
- ...
- http://example.com/a.aspx?reason=115

So when we get this url based on 'reason' we can display different message.

But the problem turns out to be that they can not send any query parameters at all. They want 15 difference URL's since they can't send query params. It doesn't make any sense to me to created 15 pages just to display a message.

Any smart ideas,that have one URL and pass the 'reason' thru some means?

EDIT: Options I'm thinking based on Answers

Try HttpRequest.PathInfo

or Second option I was thinking was to have a httphanlder read

read the path like this - HttpContext.Request.Path

based on path act. Ofcourse I will have some 15 entries like this in web.config.

`<add verb="*" path="reason1.ashx" type="WebApplication1.Class1, WebApplication1" />`
`<add verb="*" path="reason2.ashx" type="WebApplication1.Class1, WebApplication1" />`

Does that look clean?

Comment: The hell? They can redirect to "a.aspx" but not to "a.aspx?reason=nnn"? That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: i assume that hashing the end doesn't count, does it?

Comment: I really don't know what they can be done on their side. I proposed this query string param solution. But they said they can't pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoughts:

- Path Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo.aspx
  urls would be http://example.com/a.aspx/reason100, http://example.com/a.aspx/reason101, etc
- URL Rewriting : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx
  urls would be http://example.com/a/reason/100.aspx, http://example.com/a/reason/100.aspx, etc.

edit: both these approaches involve only one aspx page, but multiple urls pointing to it.

Comment: Those are for later versions of .net.

Comment: @Daniel A White: why? http://urlrewriter.net/ does URL Rewriting for .NET 1.1... The link I pointed to explains it for various IIS and ASP.NET versions...

Comment: Second option I was thinking was to have a httphanlder read 

read the path like this - HttpContext.Request.Path

based on path act. Ofcourse I will have some 15 entries like this in web.config.

<add verb="*" path="reason1.ashx" type="WebApplication1.Class1, WebApplication1" />
<add verb="*" path="reason2.ashx" type="WebApplication1.Class1, WebApplication1" />

Does that look clean?

Comment: @Broken Link: That looks very messy, having to update that in web.config all the time... But it would work, I'd guess...

Comment: Read through all the options in the rewriting link; ScottGu is usually the guy with the answers when it comes to ASP.NET...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming IIS (I run this on IIS 6 but I expect it would run on 5 as well) you could install [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/).  You could then configure different "friendly" urls a la Apache's mod-rewrite and send them as query params to a single as*x page.

Answer (score 0):

Can they send POST variables?

Too bad you are at 1.1 because the later versions support routing which allows for RESTful URLs.

Another option would to be write a custom HttpModule and intercept the incoming requests.

Comment: No, they can't send post variables.

Comment: We have few limitations with some third party products. We can't migrate to next versions.